# overflow;hidden iFrame only - (how do I keep scrollbars on the hosted web page?)

Tags: css, overflow, browser-scrollbars

Is it possible to have scrollbars on a webpage when it *must* have overflow:hidden for use in an iFrame?

Comment: Not sure what  you mean - which behaviour would you want to trigger, scrollbars or no scrollbars?

Answer (score 0):

Leave the web page as it is, and the on the `<iframe>`, use:

```
<iframe src="page.html" scrollbars="no" style="overflow: hidden;">
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is **scrolling="no"**  so it should be:

```
<iframe src="page.html" scrolling="no" style="overflow: hidden;">
```

as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7398202/1479680)