# Numerals as first characters in a line of html text are not displaying in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I'm observing this super weird bug on a news site maybe someone has seen before.
In the html text, if the first characters in a line of text are numerals, they are not displayed by the browser.

The html is coming through via a CMS, which forces the line breaks in the editor, but no 
 tags are inserted. CMS data is XSLT processed into html templates.

When this text is sent to the browser, you can see the new lines are formed (without br tags), and you see that the numerals are still within the content. But these new lines are only honored by the browser if a white-space property is set using one of the "pre" values.
Seems to be related to the white space property as i can use the inspector to add white-space:pre-line/pre-wrap and boom, they appear.

Really keen to hear some thoughts on this, or could this be a possible Chrome bug?

Link to an example article here:
tvnz.co.nz/national-news/flights-cancelled-130km-h-winds-hit-wellington-5508294

In the last paragraph of that article you can read/inspect to see the missing numeral values.

Answer (score 0):

So I really don't understand why this happens, but it has something to with the zoom setting... There are all kinds of articles about chrome bugs w/ the zoom setting, but none seem to address exactly what you were seeing...

If you inspect the page and change the zoom from 1 to .99999 it works... Again, I got the suggestion from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7742174/chrome-overflowhidden-iframe-bug) but I'm at a loss to explain exactly what is broken w/ chrome, but it does seem like a chrome bug...

Comment: Did you actually try this on the link i provided? I just tried it and has no effect...