# How to make the iframe height 100% inside div using only html inline style

Tags: html, css

With the current code below, it gives me a scrollbar, but instead, I want the full webpage to show. It seems to work if I change the height from 100% to 1150px, but I want it to be dynamic, hence, want to make it 100%. The width seems to be working fine with 100%, just not the height.

```
<div style="overflow:auto;-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch; border:1px solid black">
<iframe src="http://help.websiteos.com/websiteos/example_of_a_simple_html_page.htm" 
style="width:100%;height:100%"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown i think he means only inline styles

Comment: *With the current code below, it gives me a scrollbar, but instead, I want the full webpage to show.*  What if the full page is larger than the `viewport` ? a scrollbar will have to be introduced to enable the user access to the rest of the page, Don't you think ?

Comment: The full page is not larger than the viewport because I can make it work with 1150px.

Comment: Well that only your viewport you can't assume everyone has the same dimensions as you because it's not, if you'd like to know when i try `height:1150px` i still get scrollbars

Answer (score 0):

[`<iframe>`](https://www.startpage.com/row/search?q=iframe%20mdn&l=english) initial style is with border. 
Set the `border` to 0 and that's it.
Example:

```html
<div style="overflow:auto;-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch; border:1px solid black;">
  <iframe src="http://help.websiteos.com/websiteos/example_of_a_simple_html_page.htm" style="width:100%;height:100%; border: 0;"></iframe>
</div>
```

EDIT

If you want to hide scroll whatsoever you need to style the `<body>` tag as well (set `margin: 0;` and use the `overflow:hidden`). Now you don't need the wrapping div at all:

```
<body style="margin:0; overflow: hidden">
  <iframe src="URL" style="width: 100vw; height: 100vh; border: 0;"></iframe>
```

Comment: It still gives me the scrollbar. I want it to fully display without having to scroll up/down.

Comment: Do you mean the inner scroll on the iframe? you can add overflow:hidden to it, but note that you won't be able to scroll the content.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7398142/overflow-hidden-doesnt-work-on-chrome-with-iframes

Comment: That is not what I am looking for. Yes, I do want to hide it, but at the same time, the full page should display without having to scroll.

Comment: I edit the answer with full screen iframe without scroll option.

Comment: For some reason, I'm still getting the scroll option with your edited answer.

Comment: The document scroll? if you mean the iframe scroll try add overflow:hidden inside the inline iframe style.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bad practice to use inline style, I recommend using a css class to apply these styles

```css
.iframeStyle{
  width:100%;
  height:100%; 
  border: 0;
}

.divIFrame{
  overflow:auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="divIFrame">
  <iframe src="http://help.websiteos.com/websiteos/example_of_a_simple_html_page.htm" class="iframeStyle"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Agree, but OP did ask for inline-style. Anyway it's the same solution that i suggest - doesn't it? (:

Comment: It still gives me the scrollbar. I want it to fully display without having to scroll up/down.

Answer (score 0):

Use 100vh for height if you are targeting newer browsers that supports vh measurement.

```
<iframe style="height:100vh;width:100%" />
```

Comment: This won't solve it, now you need to omit div's border as well.

Comment: It still gives me the scrollbar. I want it to fully display without having to scroll up/down.

Comment: <iframe src="https://www.example.com" style="height:100vh;width:100%;border:0;"></iframe> would work, but internal page css takes over responsive, now if the height and is declared, then it could be scaled. that could be done with jquery or  javascript. could use a bootstrap responsive method, which would be using a jquery script in its library.